# Can somebody explain how I should use @font-face for my site?

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I'm using Amatic Bold for my website which fortunately happens to be a part of Google Fonts (https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Amatic+SC).

As I understand, I'm supposed to put this in the head of each of my html pages:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

such as index.html, downloads.html etc.

And then am I also supposed to put the `@font-face` in each of my four .css files? For example I have a main .css and then one for my `nivo-slider` etc. So would I put the `@font-face` in each .css? I'm also not sure the exact code I need to put in. I've googled `@font-face` with Google Fonts but each person seemed to type the code differently than the other whether it was the formatting or the content. I just want everybody to be able to see Amatic Bold when they visit my site despite not having it installed on their machines.

Not sure how down-voting works here but if this is a stupid question then sorry? I just started web-design the day before this post and every tutorial for webfonts seemed to be different. I felt like deleting the question but somebody might find this in the future and hopefully it clarifies for them.

Comment: When you select a font to use from [Google Fonts](http://google.com/fonts) it tells you _precisely_ what to add to your pages and gives examples. You might have to scroll the screen down to see it. Follow that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `@font-face` when using Google Fonts. They did it for you, just include the CSS file:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And use the `font-family` in your CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC';
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/12L7mpy9/).

---

*If you open the CSS file, you'll see this:*

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Amatic SC Regular'), local('AmaticSC-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/amaticsc/v6/DPPfSFKxRTXvae2bKDzp5BJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

Comment: So all I have to do is put the:

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

in each of my html heads and they will see the font? I already have it included to use the font in my css files like you showed in headers and etc. So with google fonts I don't need to use @font-face correct?

Comment: @etacarinae Correct, just put the `<link...` in your HTML and use it. There is no need to use `@font-face` :)

Comment: Thank you! I see, so the @font-face seems to be in the link. Appreciate the help as I just started to learn web design yesterday.